# How to map multi-dimensional array of JSON response with Alamofire+ObjectMapper?

Tags: json, swift, multidimensional-array, alamofire, objectmapper

I am trying to start my project with Alamofire+ObjectMapper.

I can do simple mapping with array of objects (with keys).

However, this is a must case I have to do with the following kind of JSON format, which have some problems:

#### 1: It's very nested array (3-dimensional)

#### 2: There is no key for each level's array

So I can't create object like the JSON represents. Please help!!

---

#### My JSON dictionary:

```
{
  "structure_model": [
        [
            [
                {
                    "test": "test"
                }
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

#### My model:

```
class Component: Mappable, Codable {
    var test : String = ""
    required init?(map: Map) {
        
    }
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        test <- map["test"]
    }
    
    
}

class StructureModel: Mappable, Codable {
    
    var structureModels :    [Array<Array<Component>>]?
    
    required init?(map: Map){
        
    }
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        structureModels   <- map["structure_model"]
    }
}
```

#### What I did:

```
Alamofire.request(API, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseObject { (response: DataResponse<StructureModel>) in etc... }
```

#### I expected something like:

```
structureModels = [ 
  [
    [Component, Component, ...], 
    [Component, Component, ...],
    ...
  ] ,
  [ 
    [Component, Component, ...], 
    [Component, Component, ...], 
    ...
  ] ,
  ...]
```

#### What I got:

```
structureModels = nil
```

Comment: Maybe this would give you some ideas: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/626

Comment: One suggestion would be not to use AlamofireObjectMapper (which you appear to use), but try to pre-parse your JSON manually whenever you get response with `responseJSON`.

Comment: @Hexfire thank you for your replies!! I was checked the issue on github, but it doesn’t help, since the structure of JSON is different and I still can’t figure out how to do with my JSON.

Comment: @Hexfire For your second suggestion, would you be able to give me some sample codes or reference of how to do this? It would be great and highly appreciate if you can provide me a complete code to do with my JSON!!

Answer (score 0):

If the struct of your JSON is Array of arrays you can use:

let responseArrayOfArrays = Mapper<"YourModel">().mapArrayOfArrays(JSONObject: response?.rawValue)